# Unity 3D: What method is being used in this SendMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a script currently running OnValidate() to update a GameObject while I'm in the editor. At times, when things reset, the script will run the following lines:

```
private void OnValidate()
{
    if (reset == true)
    {
        obj.transform.parent = transform;
    }
}
```

In return, I end up with some Warnings in the console like the following:

```
SendMessage cannot be called during Awake, CheckConsistency, or OnValidate
UnityEngine.Transform:set_parent(Transform)
Planet:Initialize() (at Assets/Planet.cs:46)
Planet:OnValidate() (at Assets/Planet.cs:20)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

So my question is: **What message/method is the program trying to send using SendMessage that it is unable to call?**

Answer (score 1):

See https://forum.unity.com/threads/sendmessage-cannot-be-called-during-awake-checkconsistency-or-onvalidate.428580/#post-2772943

Apparently set_parent uses SendMessage behind the covers, and that can be problematic from OnValidate calls.

Comment: Yeahh I found that one too. I'm looking for a better explanation I guess. I would love to know what exactly it could cause to go wrong so I can at least keep an eye out for it. Thanks though!